# How to syntax check PostgreSQL config files?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, configuration-files

I am often editing the pg_hda.conf file and I was just wondering if there is a way to make sure that what I just wrote is correct.

So far I'm using a test server to check my changes.

Like Apache has its `apache2ctl -t` command, does Postgres has something similar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to do this that is similar to `apache2ctl`.  If you reload the configuration files and there is a syntax error, the PostgreSQL server will complain in the log and refuse to load the new file.  So there is very little risk of messing something up by making a syntax typo.  (Of course, this won't guard you against writing semantically wrong things, but `apache2ctl` won't do that either.)  Other than that, it is probably a good idea to test changes in a test server, and have a system that propagates those changes to production in a controlled way.

Answer (score 19):

It's bee a long time, but now check is available for pg_hba.conf file:

```
select pg_hba_file_rules();
```

Also, you may use pg_file_settings view to define error in postgresql.conf:

```
select sourcefile, name,sourceline,error from pg_file_settings where error is not null;
```

example output:

```
postgres=# select sourcefile, name,sourceline,error from pg_file_settings where error is not null;
               sourcefile               |  name  | sourceline |                error
----------------------------------------+--------+------------+--------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf | lalala |          1 | unrecognized configuration parameter
```

here I put some bad stuff to check if it's true :)

Comment: This is is very interesting. I will have a look as soon as I find a job!

Comment: The second option worked great for me in checking postgresql.conf.  Thanks!

Comment: This also reports errors for parameters whose values have changed, and which would be valid, but which cannot be applied without a server restart. So not every reported error would prevent a server restart.

Answer (score 6):

refer to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151457/177071

you have another approach to test if the config file is correct.

into the command line, type `select pg_reload_conf();`

```
postgres=# select pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf
----------------
 t
(1 row)
```

This indicates your file is correct. otherwise it would fail.

Comment: It is not true. After reload conf with "t" in result I have this line the postgres log: [9692]LOG:  configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors;   unaffected changes were applied

Comment: @DShost , it may be restart required config changes. 

```
select sourcefile, name, sourceline, error from
           pg_file_settings where error is not null;
```

Comment: [pgpedia.info](https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_reload_conf.html): _Note that the boolean value returned by pg_reload_conf() merely indicates whether PostgreSQL could be successfully signalled, not whether the configuration was successfully reloaded_